# PHPMyAdmin error mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I've an problem with PHPMyAdmin, I've added  mysql_query in the php file like this

`$res = mysql_query("SELECT registration FROM settings");
 $reg = mysql_fetch_row($res);`

and else if like this

```
else if(!$reg[0])
{
    $incomplete = 1;
    $errormsg = 'Registrations closed contact support icq#: 620334543 .';
}
```

I've added column registration inside settings table in PHPMyAdmin

but i'm still getting the error message I've added to else if after i try to register
please tell me where's the problem thanks.

Comment: Add the error message. Stop using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*`ord `PDO`.

Comment: I've tried it, Does not work

Comment: What is the error message? Also, your problem is with MySQL (or PHP, more likely); phpMyAdmin is an application that assists you with administrating a MySQL database, it's not the means you use to access the database programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: i don't understand you where to add and what to change sorry im new in sql :< need more info

Comment: you can use mysqli for connection. like $servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

Comment: $sql = "SELECT registration FROM settings";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['registration'];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

Comment: i know but my question is how to fix my problem and what to change in my database to work

Comment: first of all you learn about sql. see this website. w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp